# An OS for Raspberry Pi 1 Model B (old Raspberry)

Tags: raspberry-pi

I'm looking for an OS for my **old** Raspberry; my goal is simply to launch a web browser with javascript support.

I tried :

- raspbian latest version - but my rasp is too laggy (even the `buster
  lite` version)
- raspbian old version - but here, I can't install a broswer like `midori`
  (I receive package errors)

Thanks !

Comment: It would be helpful to know exactly what happens when you launch `midori` when you are running the older version of Raspbian.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are looking for some kind of kiosk mode with a browser, you can have a look at https://github.com/futurice/chilipie-kiosk

Also, be sure you have the correct powerbrick for the Pi to have the most stable experience.